# Removing empty blocks ida api

Tags: c++, hexrays, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

i have a c++ module that removes empty block it used to work well but now I'm porting it to ida 7.7 I'm having issues.

```
mba_t *mba;
mba->remove_empty_blocks();
```

**It throws following error**

```
"remove_empty_blocks" is not a member of 'mba_t'
```

Even if it's deprecated what can be a possible solution to this, or i just ignore it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function was renamed from `bool remove_empty_blocks(void)` to `bool remove_empty_and_unreachable_blocks(void)` as of Hex-Rays 7.6. Just change the name of the function you're trying to call.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to port your CPP HexRaysDeob plugin